# find the value of a specific column in dataframe2 using the value of one column in the dataframe1 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-comparison

I did some search online. I did not find the exact case am looking for.
I need help. I have two dataframes with one of the columns containing similar items.

```
>>> df1
         ID       Item
0  0667170D      Apple
1  0644304D     Orange
2  0655323D  Pineapple
3  06284A3D     Banana
>>> df2
          ID    Item
0   TY671756  Carrot
1   JG44454D  Banana
2   07753DDD  Orange
3   0628456D   Apple
```

I have a forloop that will compare the Item column between the two dataframes and get the ones that match the closest. Ex: I take apple from 'df2' and compare it to the 'Item' column in df1. I find apple and I update it to a new column in df2 as a matched item. Now I would like to find the 'ID' of apple in 'df1' also for the matched item, in this case, apple. I would like to update the 'ID' of apple in df1 into a new column in df2.

Will I be able to do that also in the same forloop? So that I get an updated df2 with both the matched item found in df1 along with its ID number.

```
list1 = df2['Item']
list2 = df1['Item']

for i in list1:
   df2['Item'] = [difflib.get_close_matches(i, list2)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need lookup by dictionary - output are lists, because one or more values are matched:

```
list1 = df2['Item']
list2 = df1['Item']

d = df1.set_index('Item')['ID']
df2['new'] = [[d[x] for x in difflib.get_close_matches(i, list2)] for i in list1]
print (df2)
         ID    Item         new
0  TY671756  Carrot          []
1  JG44454D  Banana  [06284A3D]
2  07753DDD  Orange  [0644304D]
3  0628456D   Apple  [0667170D]
```

EDIT: For output both columns use `loop` solution:

```
list1 = df2['Item']
list2 = df1['Item']
d = df1.set_index('Item')['ID']

id2, item2 = [], []
for i in list1:
     out =  difflib.get_close_matches(i, list2)
     id2.append([d[x] for x in out])
     item2.append(out)

df2['id2new'] = id2    
df2['item2new'] = item2
print (df2)
         ID    Item      id2new  item2new
0  TY671756  Carrot          []        []
1  JG44454D  Banana  [06284A3D]  [Banana]
2  07753DDD  Orange  [0644304D]  [Orange]
3  0628456D   Apple  [0667170D]   [Apple]
```

Comment: .Thank you. This does work accurately. But misses out on one point in the original question where I have a forloop that I am using to match the Item column. So I need two new columns, one for the matches Items and another column for the matched IDs. Well, I found out how to get the matched Items but I was interested to know if the getting the IDs into another new column within the same for loop was possible. Hope my query is clear. Sorry for any confusion earlier.

Comment: Can you run this on a python3 console. You will see the kind of output I am looking for.      >>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'ID': pd.Categorical(['0TY671756', 'JG44454D', '07753DDD', '0628456D']), 'Item': pd.Categorical(['Carrot', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple']), 'MatchedID': pd.Categorical(['[]', '[06284A3D]', '[0644304D]', '[0667170D]']), 'Matched Item': pd.Categorical(['[]', '[Banana]', '[Orange]', '[Apple]' ])  })

Answer (score 2):

[Merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) both the dfs on the column `Item`

```
df3=df1.merge(df2,on="Item")
```

This will give you the matched items and their IDsfrom both dataframes

```
   ID_x    Item      ID_y
0  0667170D   Apple  0628456D
1  0644304D  Orange  07753DDD
2  06284A3D  Banana  JG44454D
```

If you want to retain the non matched items also:

```
df1.merge(df2,on="Item",how="outer")

       ID_x       Item      ID_y
0  0667170D      Apple  0628456D
1  0644304D     Orange  07753DDD
2  0655323D  Pineapple       NaN
3  06284A3D     Banana  JG44454D
4       NaN     Carrot  TY671756
```

You can rename the columns if needed.

Comment: was going to answer, but this seems better and simpler

Comment: Yes, solution working with sample data, but there is no `get_close_matches`, so it is wrong...

Comment: @Sruthi V. Thanks for the answer but the string matching for loop will be ignored if  I use the merge or join option. I did explore these earlier but wasnt fitting my need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform this using for loop below code can be used I think. Otherwise you can use @Sruthi V's answer.

```
newColumn = []
for value in df2['Item'].values:
    if (len(df1[df1['Item']==value].values) > 0):
        newColumn.append(df1[df1['Item']==value].iloc[0,0])
    else:
        newColumn.append(np.NaN)

df2['NewColumn'] = newColumn


>>> df2

         ID    Item NewColumn
0  TY671756  Carrot       NaN
1  JG44454D  Banana  06284A3D
2  07753DDD  Orange  0644304D
3  0628456D   Apple  0667170D
```

Comment: Thank you. This does work. But misses out on one point in the original question where I have a forloop that I am using to match the Item column. So I need two new columns, one for the matches Items and another column for the matched IDs. Well, I found out how to get the matched Items but I was interested to know if the getting the IDs into another new column within the same for loop was possible. Hope my query is clear. Sorry for any confusion earlier.